# How to access the receiver of a method reference?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, method-reference, kotlin-reflect

I have a method reference (represented by the `kotlin.reflect.KFunction0` interface). What I would like to do is to get the `receiver` object of the method reference.

For example:

```kotlin
data class MyClass(val name: String)

val john = MyClass("John")
val methodReference = john::toString

methodReference.receiver // doesn't work!
```

The `receiver` of `methodReference` is the object `john`. If I look into the IntelliJ debugger, `methodReference` has a `receiver` field which indeed points to `john`. But I cannot find a way to actually access it in my code.

Is there some sort of workaround for this?

Comment: It's probably worth asking _why_ you want to get that; this feels like an XY problem.  (Reflection is rarely a good solution in general-purpose code; it's slow, ugly, fragile, insecure, and turns compilation errors into runtime crashes.  It's needed for frameworks, plugins, build tools, etc., but outside those there's usually a better approach.)

Comment: @gidds It is for a framework. The underlying API (which eventually binds to C++) requires a receiver object and a method name explicitly. I would like to be able to use method references as a single argument; but for that I need to be able to extract the receiver from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is Kotlin/JVM, the `receiver` field you see is a protected field declared in [`CallableReference`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/internal/CallableReference.java#L32). You can get this using Java reflection.

```
val f = someINstance::foo
val receiverField = CallableReference::class.java.getDeclaredField("receiver")
receiverField.isAccessible = true
println(receiverField.get(f))
```

I'm not sure if this field is *guaranteed* to be called `receiver`, or whether it will exist at all, in future versions. I cannot find any official documentation on this.

Also note that not every `KFunction0` has a receiver. When this is the case, `receiverField.get(f)` would return `CallableReference.NO_RECEIVER`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes it's Kotlin/JVM. Just like you, I had no luck finding any documentation on this. And yes, of course not all KFunction0 instances will have a receiver, it's perfectly fine if it's null. I'll give it a shot with your solution :)